# C# /windows forms: linking trackbar and textfield with a factor

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, trackbar

linking a trackbar and a textfield is very easy in windows forms.
it is like this:
textBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", trackBar, "Value");

the problem is, that trackbars only allow for integer values but i want to have floating point values.
so i usually just divide the value by 100, since on the trackbar the value is not directly visible to the user. 
but in the textbox it is.

so is it possible to link these two with a factor of 100?

thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The line of code you have adds a `Binding` object to the text box's `DataBindings` collection.

The `Binding` class has events called `Format` and `Parse`, which you can use to perform the division (the `Format` event takes a value from the trackbar and formats it for the text box) and the multiplication (the `Parse` event takes a value from the text box and scales it for the trackbar).

Answer (score 1):

You can use intermediate variables like below:

```
    public double v{set;get;}
    public int v100
    {
        set { v = value / 100D; }
        get { return (int)(v* 100D); }
    }
```

and blind them with Controls.

```
    trackBar.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Value", PtParams, "v100"));
    textBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", PtParams, "v"));
```